# sympy solve function as function

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I want to solve f(x) from

```
(Eq(2*f(x)+f(1/x),1/x))
```

the expected output is

f(x) = (2-x^2)/(3*x)

I try

```
 solve((Eq(2*f(x)+f(1/x),1/x)),f(x))
```

This answer contains f(1/x) : (-x*f(1/x) + 1)/(2*x)

How to get f(x) = (2-x^2)/(3*x) in sympy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think sympy will solve functional equations like this in the way you want, but you could separate your particular equation into two: 2y+z = 1/x and 2z+y = x where y(1/x) = z(x) and let sympy solve for both y and z:

```
In [5]: x, y, z = Symbol('x'), Symbol('y'), Symbol('z')
In [6]: solve((Eq(2*y+z,1/x), Eq(2*z+y,x)),y,z)
Out[6]: {y: (-x**2 + 2)/(3*x), z: (2*x**2 - 1)/(3*x)}
```

So y is the f(x) that you want here.

Comment: Slightly off topic: you can use `x, y, z = symbols('x y z')` instead.